# Does Bhagwat Puran mention that Lord Krishna was born to annihilate Kshatriyas?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, caste-system

In [Annihilation of Caste](http://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/projects/mmt/ambedkar/web/readings/aoc_print_2004.pdf), Section 18, Dr. Ambedkar says that

> The Bhagwat tells us very definitely that Krishna had taken avatar for
>   one sacred purpose: and that was, to annihilate the Kshatriyas.

Is it correct? Does Bhagwat Puran mention the above?

Answer (score 6):

That is not correct. [Shrimada Bhagavatam Canto 10, Chapter 1](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/1) describes the cause of appearance of Lord Krishna. It states that the mother Earth was overburdened by many demons who were posing like kings. So, she approached lord Brahma to get rid of them and lord Brahma approached Lord Vishnu for the same. So, lord appeared on the earth.

> bhūmir dṛpta-nṛpa-vyāja-
>   daityānīka-śatāyutaiḥ
>   ākrāntā bhūri-bhāreṇa
>   brahmāṇaṁ śaraṇaṁ yayau
>
> SB 10.1.17 — Once when mother earth was overburdened by hundreds of thousands of military phalanxes of various conceited demons dressed like kings, she approached Lord Brahmā for relief.

In the very [next chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/2) it was confirmed that the Lord wanted to protect Yadus (a Kshatriya clan) from other demonic Kings.

> rī-śuka uvāca
>   pralamba-baka-cāṇūra-
>   tṛṇāvarta-mahāśanaiḥ
>   muṣṭikāriṣṭa-dvivida-
>   pūtanā-keśī-dhenukaiḥ
>
> anyaiś cāsura-bhūpālair
>   bāṇa-bhaumādibhir yutaḥ
>   yadūnāṁ kadanaṁ cakre
>   balī māgadha-saṁśrayaḥ
>
> SB 10.2.1-2 — Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: Under the protection of Magadharāja, Jarāsandha, the powerful Kaṁsa began persecuting the kings of the Yadu dynasty. In this he had the cooperation of demons like Pralamba, Baka, Cāṇūra, Tṛṇāvarta, Aghāsura, Muṣṭika, Ariṣṭa, Dvivida, Pūtanā, Keśī, Dhenuka, Bāṇāsura, Narakāsura and many other demoniac kings on the surface of the earth.
>
> te pīḍitā niviviśuḥ
>   kuru-pañcāla-kekayān
>   śālvān vidarbhān niṣadhān
>   videhān kośalān api
>
> SB 10.2.3 — Persecuted by the demoniac kings, the Yādavas left their own kingdom and entered various others, like those of the Kurus, Pañcālas, Kekayas, Śālvas, Vidarbhas, Niṣadhas, Videhas and Kośalas.
>
> eke tam anurundhānā
>   jñātayaḥ paryupāsate
>   hateṣu ṣaṭsu bāleṣu
>   devakyā augraseninā
>
> saptamo vaiṣṇavaṁ dhāma
>   yam anantaṁ pracakṣate
>   garbho babhūva devakyā
>   harṣa-śoka-vivardhanaḥ
>
> SB 10.2.4-5 — Some of their relatives, however, began to follow Kaṁsa’s principles and act in his service. After Kaṁsa, the son of Ugrasena, killed the six sons of Devakī, a plenary portion of Kṛṣṇa entered her womb as her seventh child, arousing her pleasure and her lamentation. That plenary portion is celebrated by great sages as Ananta, who belongs to Kṛṣṇa’s second quadruple expansion.
>
> bhagavān api viśvātmā
>   viditvā kaṁsajaṁ bhayam
>   yadūnāṁ nija-nāthānāṁ
>   yoga-māyāṁ samādiśat
>
> SB 10.2.6 — To protect the Yadus, His personal devotees, from Kaṁsa’s attack, the Personality of Godhead, Viśvātmā, the Supreme Soul of everyone, ordered Yoga-māyā as follows.

So, from these references it is clear that the Lord's purpose was to kill only those who do not follow the path of Dharma (righteousness). If His intention was to kill all Kshatriyas He should not have helped Pandavas.

And finally, in [Bhagavat Gita, Chapter 4, Verse 7](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/7) Lord Krishna described his purpose:

> yadā yadā hi dharmasya
>   glānir bhavati bhārata
>   abhyutthānam adharmasya
>   tadātmānaṁ sṛjāmy aham
>
> Whenever and wherever there is a decline in religious practice, O descendant of Bharata, and a predominant rise of irreligion – at that time I descend Myself.

Comment: Can you post the original Sanskrit text for above references of  Shrimada Bhagavatam? Sometimes, meaning is lost in translation.

Comment: @dharm0us Check the updated answer.

Comment: @dharm0us The meaning is indeed lost when _someone_  misinterpreted and told the wrong definitions of the shlokas given in the Bhagavatam. :P

Comment: @Sarvabhouma that's why I am asking if you or anyone can share the original text.

Comment: @dharm0us What do you mean by original text? In my answer I am quoting the original text.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I meant the original Sanskrit Text, which you have posted now. Thanks.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani after this speech was published, Gandhi had written a counter to Ambedkar saying that he misquoted the Sanskrit texts. To which Ambedkar replied that he took references from Tilak's texts (Bal Gangadhar Tilak). By any chance, would you have access to the texts which Ambedkar is refering to?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani here is Ambedkar's response: "The first point made by the Mahatma is that the texts cited by me are not authentic. I confess I am no authority on this matter. But I should like to state that the texts cited by me are all taken from the writings of the late Mr. Tilak, who was a recognised authority on the Sanskrit language and on the Hindu Shastras."

Comment: @dharm0us I have to look into this. I will get back to you after that.

Comment: @dharm0us But still, I feel Dr. Ambedkar should have looked into originals atleast after Mahatma Gandhi's counter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74800/discussion-between-triyugi-narayan-mani-and-dharm0us).